# FlaskAdmin : triggering a function when clicking SAVE button

Tags: python, flask-admin

I'd like to add a bunch of program anytime the user is adding data to the model, after clicking the save button (or delete / edit).

In my program, one column is filled by raw SQL queries. So before inserting the record in the model, I'd like to program to test the query to make sure the SQL language has been correctly imputed.

here is the model:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

admin = Admin(app, template_mode='bootstrap3')

class rGraphs(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'rGraphs'
    graph_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    Description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)
    TABLE_SRC = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=True)
    G_QUERY = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)
    colfilters = db.relationship('tblParamColFilter', backref='rGraphs', lazy='dynamic')
    coltransfos = db.relationship('tblParamColformat', backref='rGraphs', lazy='dynamic')
    graphlayouts = db.relationship('tblParamGraphLayout', backref='rGraphs', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.Description

class rGraphsView(ModelView):
    form_columns = ['graph_id', 'Description', 'TABLE_SRC','G_QUERY']

admin.add_view(rGraphsView(rGraphs, db.session, name='Graphics list'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #si modele doit etre mis a jour
    #manager.run()

    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the following methods in your inherited class `rGraphsView`: `update_model(self, form, model)`, `create_model(self, form)` and `delete_model(self, model)`.

A simple example:

```
class rGraphsView(ModelView):
    form_columns = ['graph_id', 'Description', 'TABLE_SRC','G_QUERY']

    def allow_update(self, form, model):
        # test your form data and/or existing model data here
        print form.G_QUERY.data
        print model.G_QUERY
        # return True or False 
        return True

    def allow_create(self, form):
        # test your form data here
        print form.G_QUERY.data
        # return True or False 
        return True

    def allow_delete(self, model):
        # test your model data here
        print model.G_QUERY
        # return True or False 
        return True

    def update_model(self, form, model):

        if allow_update(form, model):
            # passes our allow_update test call super method
            return super(rGraphsView, self).update_model(form, model)
        else:
            flash('Your failed update message here', 'error')

    def create_model(self, form):

        if allow_create(form):
            # passes our allow_create test call super method
            return super(rGraphsView, self).create_model(form)
        else:
            flash('Your failed create message here', 'error')

    def delete_model(self, model):

        if allow_delete(model):
            # passes our allow_delete test call super method
            return super(rGraphsView, self).delete_model(model)
        else:
            flash('Your failed delete message here', 'error')
```

Comment: got it, will have a try thks